# First Activity Date

Tags: apex

I have created a new field First_Activity_Call_Duration__c in the object Opportunity. It is supposed to hold a value from the first related task that was created against the Opportunity.

Next, I wrote a trigger on Task, which picks the relevant Opportunity, and updates the field with the value from the task *if it is null*.

The problem: Opportunities which already have a task will not get the updated value in this field.

What is the right way to fix this problem? Should I run batch apex to fill these fields on all opportunities first? Any other pitfalls anyone can see?

Comment: I'd export the Ops and Tasks, and dataload the 'old' values, but without knowing your data, it may not be applicable.

Comment: or, you could, write an anonymous apex script in developer console that did the work and save yourself the trouble of writing a batch class and testing it (of course, if you have tens of thousands of opportunities, the batch class makes sense or the data loader approach as @homej suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would use a batch to back fill these dates. Your `queryLocator` will probably be as simple as:

```
SELECT Id FROM Opportunity
```

Then, you will need a static method which accepts a list of `Opportunity` records (not `Task`), query for the earliest `Task` for each, and assign that value.

One other pitfall I would call out is that in your `Task` trigger you will be working with a collection of child records which could potentially share a parent, so make sure you group and sort your `Task` records properly to avoid arbitrary collision.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that has more general uses over time is to use the Task trigger to signal an Opportunity trigger that there is a rollup to do (rather than the Task trigger updating the `First_Activity_Call_Duration__c` field directly.

Call this new Opportunity field `Force_RSF__c` (Boolean)

When the Oppo before update trigger executes, if `Force_rsf__c` is true, it reads through the list (of bulkified) Tasks, computes the `First_Activity_Call_Duration__c` and then turns off `Force_rsf__c`

Now, you can use Data Loader and merely export all Opportunities, then reload the Opportunities setting `Force_rsf__c` to true. The trigger will execute, troll each Oppo's tasks, and update accordingly through the implicit DML of the before update trigger context

That said, for one-off, I'd probably do this with Developer Console anonymous apex if there weren't tens of thousands of Oppos